# VTK disable rotation python

Tags: python, pyqt, vtk

I have a pyqt app with a vtkRenderWindow embedded in it displaying a 2D mesh. As i'm displaying a 2D mesh, i would like it to stay 2D, in order to do that i need to disable the rotation in the Interactor. I searched arounx the web but couldn't find anything that worked..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable rotation you just have to setup the interactor style for 2D images. In this case, `vtkInteractorStyleImage` will do it. Here is an example:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage> style = vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);
```

Take this example (https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/ConstrainedDelaunay2D) and add the above lines below the following line:

```
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
```

Hope it helps!